# To count how many consecutive pairs in a list of numbers

Tags: python, list, count

To count how many consecutive pairs of number in a list, here's an example:

```
[150,151,152,262]
```

There are 2 consecutive pairs, which are 150 & 151, 151 & 152.

I try below:

```
import more_itertools as mit
import itertools

iterable = [150,151,152,262]

tem_list = [list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(iterable)]
# [[150, 151, 152], [262]]

i = 0
for t in tem_list:
    if len(t) == 1:
        i = 0
    if len(t) == 2:
        i += 1
    if len(t) == 3:
        i += 2      
print (i)
```

But it doesn't work. What went wrong, and how can I correct it?

Comment: `i = 0` resets the count every time you hit a sublist with only one item. Why not `count += len(t) - 1`?

Comment: Might be a bit easier to track what previous item was while iterating the list.

Comment: Or simply `[len(t) - 1 for t in tem_list]`

Comment: @Mortz, thanks. can you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a grouping function for this is overkill. You can use zip() to pair each item with its successor and add the result of comparing them using the sum function:

```
L = [150,151,152,262]
C = sum(a+1==b for a,b in zip(L,L[1:]))
print(C) # 2
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your code is resetting the count to 0 as it loops through each inner list.

Given that you have already created the `tem_list` - you can get the pairs with simply `[len(t) - 1 for t in tem_list]`

Comment: superb! (wish to see yours earlier :))